# Are textlive-xxx-doc packages required for installing LyX?

Tags: software-installation

Whenever I install LyX using `sudo apt-get install lyx`, then I find packages like `texlive-fonts-recommended-doc`,`texlive-latex-base-doc`,`texlive-latex-extra-doc`, etc. among the dependencies. Some of these files are huge (texlive-latex-extra-doc is 190MB), and they all seem to be documentation files.

Do I really need to install these for using LyX? If not, then how do i avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should be only *Recommended packages*, so that you can avoid to install them by issuing in the first place the command

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install lyx
```